# Unable to pass the spark developer code check, encountered binary compatibility error

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I'm a new spark contributor. I want to add class weight support for the random forest classifier, which is described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9478

I've finished the function implementation and I'm following the code contributing instructions here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-PreparingtoContributeCodeChanges

In the instructions, it says 'Run all tests with ./dev/run-tests to verify that the code still compiles, passes tests, and passes style checks'. When I was running the test, my code cannot pass the binary compatibility check.

The log says:

```
[error]  * method this(scala.Enumeration#Value,org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Impurity,Int,Int,Int,scala.Enumeration#Value,scala.collection.immutable.Map,Int,Double,Int,Double,Boolean,Int)Unit 
in class org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy does not have a correspondent in current version
[error]    filter with: ProblemFilters.exclude[DirectMissingMethodProblem]("org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy.this")
```

I changed the file "org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy" because I need to change the interface of this class. What I did is adding a new input parameter like this:

```
    class Strategy @Since("1.3.0") (
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var algo: Algo,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var impurity: Impurity,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var maxDepth: Int,
    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var numClasses: Int = 2,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var maxBins: Int = 32,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var quantileCalculationStrategy: QuantileStrategy = Sort,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map[Int, Int] = Map[Int, Int](),
    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var minInstancesPerNode: Int = 1,
    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var minInfoGain: Double = 0.0,
    @Since("1.0.0") @BeanProperty var maxMemoryInMB: Int = 256,
    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var subsamplingRate: Double = 1,
    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var useNodeIdCache: Boolean = false,
-    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var checkpointInterval: Int = 10) extends Serializable {
+    @Since("1.2.0") @BeanProperty var checkpointInterval: Int = 10,
+    @Since("2.0.0") @BeanProperty var classWeights: Array[Double] = Array(1, 1))
```

How can I fix this issue or what is the direction to debug?

--------------------------------  An update  ------------------------------

I'm not one of the authors who have made a pull request for this problem in the JIRA. I have a new implementation which needs less memory to achieve the same goal. My code can be found here: https://github.com/n-triple-a/spark and the branch 'weightedRandomForest' has the problem mentioned above.

I can currently solve this problem by adding a constructor in the **Strategy** class having the first 13 params(or without the **classWeights** in the argument list) like this:

```
    this(var algo: Algo,
      impurity: Impurity,
      maxDepth: Int,
      numClasses: Int,
      maxBins: Int,
      quantileCalculationStrategy: QuantileStrategy,
      categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map[Int, Int],
      minInstancesPerNode: Int,
      minInfoGain: Double,
      maxMemoryInMB: Int,
      subsamplingRate: Double,
      useNodeIdCache: Boolean,
      checkpointInterval: Int) {
    this(algo, impurity, maxDepth, numClasses, maxBins, 
         quantileCalculationStrategy, categoricalFeaturesInfo, minInstancesPerNode,
         minInfoGain, maxMemoryInMB, subsamplingRate, useNodeIdCache, 
         checkpointInterval, Array(1.0, 1.0))
    }
```

I also changed the scalastyle's definition on the maximum number of arguments allowed for a function, which is 10 by default. But it is weird to me because there is a default value binding to the **classWeights**. Why do I have to add a redundant constructor?

Comment: I do not see the file `Strategy` mentioned in the 12 changed files associated PR - could you help out on that?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I've updated the description. Please feel free to ask other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The PR https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/9008/files associated with your JIRA does not appear to include the `Strategy` class.  Please update the PR including that file and then let us know if further issues occur.

Comment: I haven't made any pull requests yet. I saw their code and I think I got a better implementation idea to achieve the same goal. My code is here: [link](https://github.com/n-triple-a/spark)  (under the 'weightedRandomForest' branch).